# GitLab で MATLAB ファイルが構文ハイライトされない

Tags: git, gitlab

GitLab CE を Omnibus package のインストラクション通り， Ubuntu-14.04 に導入しました．

しかしながら， GitLab で管理しているレポジトリの中の MATLAB スクリプトが構文ハイライト(syntax highlight)されません．

もともとこういう仕様なのかもしれないのですが， GitHub のようにハイライトするにはなにか導入すべき物があるのでしょうか．．．？

Comment: GitLab のバージョン番号はいくらでしょうか。バグの可能性があります。

Comment: GitLab 7.6.2 です．

Comment: 7.6.2 ですか。 "[Issue #665: HLJS language autodetection / syntax highlighting fails](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/665)" に報告が上がっていたので、それを疑いましたが、件に対する修正は、すでに [7.6.2 であたっている](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/b8fcaa7f4126ce2b5fe0436197b2aacc1be84e96)ようです。
MATLAB ファイルの構文ハイライト機能自体は、[8か月前のコミット](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/47d5ef4bd54ac493a35d190d0909059b6e35c0fe)にありますので、 7.6.2 でデグレっている可能性はあります。（GitLab に機能はあるが、設定ミスやバグ等の何らかの理由でハイライトされていない、という状態と考えてください。該当箇所はまた変更が加えられていますので次のバージョンもしくはレポジトリにあるソースで直るかもしれません。）

Comment: 調査していただき，ありがとうございます．ご紹介いただいたissueなどから，ハイライトがうまく働かないバージョンにあたってしまったものと理解しています．次のバージョンまで待ってみます．

Comment: 試せなかったのが残念です。そのうち誰かが回答してくれるでしょう XD

Answer (score 3):

Matlab と Objective-C　はどちらも拡張子が .m のためObjective-Cのコードとして解釈されてしまったためハイライトがつかないのだと思います.

言語の設定である思われる[languages.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)　を見るとデフォルトでは matlab の拡張子は .matlab と設定してあります.なのでlanguages.yml のObjective-CとMatlabの記述を変更すればハイライトがつくのではないでしょうか.

Answer (score 3):

もし、他の方が回答しているように、拡張子の問題であった場合、 .matlab 以外のをMATLABとしてハイライトさせる方法もあります。

プロジェクトのルートディレクトリに、`.gitattributes` というファイルを作って、中に設定を書きます。

```
*.m gitlab-language=matlab
```

これで、拡張子 `.m`のファイルをMATLABとして認識させてハイライトさせることができます。

[本家の説明ページ](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/git_attributes.html)